# Como deixar o Usuário inserir o tamanho do vetor? (C++)

Tags: array, c++

Olá, queria saber uma forma de deixar o usuário definir o tamanho do vetor a ser lido.
Tive essa primeiro ideia, mas não consigo imprimir na tela depois de lido.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    //Variáveis
    int x,i;
    int vet[x];

    cout<<"\n Qual o tamanho do vetor? ";
    cin>>x;

    for (i = 0;i<x;++i){
        //Guarda os valores inseridos no vet[i]
        cin>> *(vet + i);
    }
     //Mostra na tela usando ponteiro
     
    cout<<"\n Mostrando valores: "<<endl;
    for(i = 0;i<x;++i){
        //Mostra na tela valores guardados no vet[i]
        cout<<*(vet + i)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: o tamanho do vetor deve ser algo conhecido em tempo de compilação, uma constante. Ou leia o tamanho e use `malloc()`  para criar o vetor do tamanho certo

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Lembre que é importante saber o tamanho do vetor que está criando, declare o vet depois de atribuir o valor de x

```
int x,i;   

cout<<"\n Qual o tamanho do vetor? ";
cin>>x;
int vet[x];
```

Comment: o tamanho do vetor deve ser algo conhecido em tempo de compilação, uma constante. Ou leia o tamanho e use `malloc()`  para criar o vetor do tamanho certo